# SQL Server Management Studio reset all styles

Tags: sql-server, settings, ssms, sql-server-2014, ssms-2014

So I messed up my sql server management studio when I was trying to make it have a "dark theme" as I use it a lot and it was starting to wear on my eyes. While doing this, I specified for the output window to have a black background with white text. Then I realized that the output window wouldn't give me a black background anyway, *sigh*, but it would give me white text. So now I have this lovely problem where there is white text on a white background that can only be faintly seen when highlighting the results...

It's very annoying. I know I was stupid to try to give SSMS a "theme" but I had to try something.

So now the problem. When I go back in to try to edit the settings for the output window (Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> Output Window) to try to restore defaults or change any color, SSMS crashes.

Does anyone know how to reset all styles for SSMS, or change a specific style (like making text black again) or anything? I really don't want to have to reinstall SQL Server.

This is SQl Server Management Studio 2014

Comment: You don't have to reinstall SQL Server, but you may want to look into the idea of reinstalling/repairing the Client Tools. I think you can start the process in Control Panel/Programs and Features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue as you but found the solution.

Choose another option under "Show settings for:" after you reset the "Use Default" for "Text Editor" and before clicking on OK.

[MS SQL Server Forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9070acd9-6539-427e-bcab-25f05d343c8e/sql-server-management-studio-has-stopped-working-when-changing-fonts-and-colors?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade)

Comment: Oh my gosh! Thank you a billion times over. Repairing didn't work but this strangely did.

Answer (score -1):

Just in case if you still haven't get your answer, you should be changing Grid Result instead of Output Window.